# Implicit conversion with operator float() and float() const with static members

Tags: c++, static, type-conversion, constants

I just ran into a problem when trying to overload `operator float()` and `operator float() const`. I thought I could use both overloads to provide different versions for "do things" and "just read"... but it turns out, that with static instances of the class which contains these overloads I can't.

Boiled down the problem pretty much reduces to this:

```
// Does some math and should convert to float
struct ToFloat
{
  // float conversion here
  operator float()
  {
    cout << "called operator float() of " << s << "\n";
    f += 1.0f;
    return f;
  }

  // just get current value here
  operator float() const
  {
    cout << "called operator float() *const* of " << s << "\n";
    return f;
  }

  float f;
  std::string s;
};

// Uses a static and a normal member of ToFloat
struct Container
{
  // return both instances (with some more math before)
  operator float()
  {
    return s * m;
  }

  // just provide read access
  operator float() const
  {
    return s * m;
  }

  static inline ToFloat s { 1.0f, "static" };
  ToFloat m { 1.0f, "member" };
};

// Uses the container, but must also provide read-only access
struct Use
{
  // Give me operator float() of my container
  float get()
  {
    return c;
  }

  // Give me operator float() const of my container
  float getC() const
  {
    return c;
  }

  Container c {};
};

int main()
{
  Use u {};

  printf("getC() %f \n\n", u.getC());
  printf("get() %f \n\n", u.get());
  printf("getC() %f \n\n", u.getC());
}
```

Which produces the following output...

```
called operator float() of static
called operator float() *const* of member
getC() 2.000000 

called operator float() of static
called operator float() of member
get() 6.000000 

called operator float() of static
called operator float() *const* of member
getC() 8.000000
```

I don't really get why the static instance of `ToFloat` always uses the non-`const` conversion, even if called from a function declared `const`? What rule applies here?

Comment: The static member isn't `const` just because an instance of the class is `const`. Neither does it *appear* as `const` from that instance's code. Unrelated, but using `float` instead of default `double` is generally just an invitation of sillywarnings, and maintainers wasting time trying to figure out why the heck you're doing that.

Comment: My target platform does not support double in hardware.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Regarding `float` vs. `double`: really? I'd say that in lots of number-crunching code, a lot of thought goes into where the precision of `double` is worth the speed & memory costs.

Comment: @Angew: It's true that sometimes `float` can be useful: it's in the language for a reason. When  you have a zillion values it's half the space, and when you process them more or less sequentially that's speed for you, also. But as a general default `float` is less convenient, sometimes slower than `double`, and generally of no advantage. There's nothing in the OP's code that indicates a reasonable use case for `float`. However, he's explained that it's due to hardware restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static data member `Container::s` is simply of type `ToFloat`. It is always accessed directly, never through an implicit dereference of `this`. In other words, the container's `const` operator is effectively this:

```
operator float() const
{
  return Container::s * this->m;
}
```

From this, it should be obvious that there's no reason for `Container::s` to be treated as `const` just because `this` is a `const Container *`. If you want it to be treated as `const`, you have to qualify it explicitly:

```
operator float() const
{
  return std::as_const(s) * m;
}
```